# Example diffeomorphism of a rectangle onto itself

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, diffeomorphism

The Wikipedia article for [Diffeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism) has the below picture of an example diffeomorphism of a square onto itself, but it does not seem to specify the specific mapping used to create it.  Obviously, I don't need to know the exact mapping used to make the example image, but what would be a similar diffeomorphism that would map an arbitrary rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at the x,y origin onto itself and would produce a somewhat similar style of grid distortion?  What would the inverse then be?

The application I'm trying implement is pretty much exactly what the image is: distorting a rectangular grid in different ways such that it can be inverted.  I'm just trying to find a concrete example as a starting point as I'm am still rather unfamiliar with this area of mathematics.  So pardon any misunderstandings I may be having.

[image: diffeomorphism]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following figure was drawn with Mathematica. I have used a rotation of the plane by a variable angle $\theta$. This $\theta$ is ${\pi\over4}$ at the origin and decreases to $0$ when we come the boundary of the square. In fact
$$\theta(x,y)={\pi\over4}\,\cos x\>\cos y\ .$$

[image]

Comment: Perfect example.  In this example, I assume that if this is a diffeomorphic mapping then an inverse mapping must exist.  Do you know of an approach one could take to compute the inverse mapping for this example?

Comment: Maybe there are "elementary" examples with an "elementary" inverse. Inverting the above example in elementary terms seems impossible.